# Are there any special kinds of parser for SAML 2.0

Tags: security, networking, metadata, saml

I need to know do we have any special kind of parser to SAML metadata file.We have XML parsers like DOM SAX STAx as these parsers do we have any parser to access SAML metadata elements as java objects?

Answer (score 1):

OpenSAML is a specialised java library that also can parse metadata. Have a look on [my post about SAML Metadata and OpenSAML](http://mylifewithjava.blogspot.no/2012/02/reading-metadata-with-opensaml.html)